# Unity Scene - Restart button causing processes to stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I need help with my restart button ..when I reload a scene all processes will stop. 
//start**

```
void Start()
{
    if (NoAnsweredQuestion == null || NoAnsweredQuestion.Count == 0)
    {
        NoAnsweredQuestion = question.ToList<Question>();
    }

    SetcurrentQuestion();
    StartCoroutine("CountDownTimer");
}
```

**//Setcurrentquestion**

```
void SetcurrentQuestion()
{
    int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, NoAnsweredQuestion.Count);
    currentQuestion = NoAnsweredQuestion[randomQuestionIndex];

    factText.text = currentQuestion.fact;
    correctAnswerText.text = currentQuestion.answered;
}
```

**//transition**

```
IEnumerator TransitiontoNextQuestion()
{
    NoAnsweredQuestion.Remove(currentQuestion);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delaybetweenquestion);

    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

Comment: where's your restart button's information or what is the error?

Comment: i have no error sir.

Comment: So what do you want? Do you want to thank you to creating that unknown game? or you want publishing your game?

Comment: no sir...but my problem is when i click the  button restart the reload scene is will freeze or will stop processing entire scene

Answer (score 0):

this my restart button of my game

```
public void restart()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    WWW www = new WWW(restartBegGrammarIAQ, form);
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Edit it into your question